# How to fix 'TypeError: argument of type 'URL' is not iterable' when trying to look for values in a url with aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

When using AIOHTTP and returning the url of a request, im trying to iterate and look for certain values in the url. If theres a certain value it has to do something with the url.

I have already tried parsing over the requrl.url using for loops but that also doesnt work. When i append the requrl.url to a list it appends the link like so: `[URL('https://twitter.com/home')]`

```py
async with session.get(https://twitter.com/) as requrl:
    print (requrl.url)

    if 'home' in requrl.url:
        #do something
```

The expected results would be to obviously meet the condition if `home` is in the `requrl.url` but when doing through this code, the condition is not met.

The error given is `TypeError: argument of type 'URL' is not iterable`

Again, if i append the requrl.url to a list the list reads as so `[URL('https://twitter.com/home')]`

Im assuming because of the URL part it the list above when parsing it for a value it cant find do it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: convert it to `str`.. `if "home" in str(requrl.url): #do stuff`

Comment: wow that was so basic, so dumb of me. Thank you @בנימיןכהן

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Had to change the value to a string.

```
async with session.get(https://twitter.com/) as requrl:
    print (requrl.url)

    if 'home' in str(requrl.url):
        #do something
```